# Jquery how $(this) work

Tags: jquery

Simple question 
What is wrong with this code.

I work on a navbar. icon change on rezize.

Edit:

```
//from desktop to mobile resize
      function desktop_menu_resize(){

        if ($(".has-sub").hasClass("open")) {

          $('.has-sub.open').find(".fa-angle-down").removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-up");
          }



        if ($('.sub-has-sub').hasClass('open')) {

         $('.sub-has-sub.open').find(".fa-angle-right").removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-up");
        }
          else
         {
          $('.sub-has-sub').not('open').find(".fa-angle-right").removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-down");
         }

      };
```

Comment: Please, post the entire function....

Comment: I recommend that you read through the [jQuery API Docs](https://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you can't do this:

```
$(this) = $(".sub-has-sub");
```

You're trying to assign the result of a function to... the result of another function.  Store the result in a variable instead:

```
var elements = $(".sub-has-sub");
elements.find(".fa-angle-right").removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-up");
```

Or, really, you don't need the variable at all for this example:

```
$(".sub-has-sub").find(".fa-angle-right").removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-up");
```

Comment: Thanks i am new to jQuery, so uits a learning process right now